# Faster way to count occurrences of values over a certain value in a column of lists in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataFrame. Each row of column data is a list containing around 50 data points. And I want to count the number of occurrences of numbers over 50 and over 20.

```
>>> df['data'].head(10)
0    [33.23, 51.02, 32.01 ...
1    [99.04, 38.06, 39.57...
2    [96.04, 96.72, 401.93...
3    [96.64, 99.15, 99.83...
4    [96.71, 38.93, 53.02....
5    [88.72, 37.61, 39.61...
6    [38.93, 88.72, 37.31...
7    [88.72, 39.61, 35.71...
8    [97.44, 99.04, 88.56....
9    [00.14, 89.61, 39.95...
```

If we transform the df to dic, it would look like below:

```
>>> df.to_dict()
{'data': {'row1': [33.23, 51.02, 32.01,...], 'row2': [99.04, 38.06, 39.57,...],'row3': [96.04, 96.72, 401.93,...],'row4'...}}
```

The expected result i would like to get is a new column called result and it stores the count of values in data column over 50.0 or over 20.0 if no values are over 50.0:

```
>>> df.show()
         data                            result
0    [33.23, 51.02, 32.01 ...              1
1    [99.04, 38.06, 39.57...               1
2    [96.04, 96.72, 401.93...              3
3    [96.64, 99.15, 99.83...               3
4    [96.71, 38.93, 53.02....              2
```

This is the method i used:

```
   pandas_data_frame[result_column] = pandas_data_frame.apply(
                lambda row: count_values(row[data]), axis=1)

   def count__values(numlist):
     count1 = sum(
                x >= 50.0 for x in list) 
     count2 = sum(
                x >= 20.0 for x in list) 
     return count1 if count1 > 0 else count2
```

However the dataframe can be extremely huge and i was wondering if there is any pandas method to improve the performance? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible sample of your dataframe. For example, post the output of `df["data"].head(10).to_dict()`. Also post your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `explode` and `groupby`:

```
df[[">=50", ">=20"]] = (df.explode("data") 
                          .groupby(level=0)["data"]
                          .agg([lambda x: x.ge(50).sum(), 
                                lambda x: x.ge(20).sum()]
                               )
                        )

>>> df
                     data  >=50  >=20
0   [33.23, 51.02, 32.01]     1     3
1   [99.04, 38.06, 39.57]     1     3
2  [96.04, 96.72, 401.93]     3     3
3   [96.64, 99.15, 99.83]     3     3
4   [96.71, 38.93, 53.02]     2     3
5   [88.72, 37.61, 39.61]     1     3
6   [38.93, 88.72, 37.31]     1     3
7   [88.72, 39.61, 35.71]     1     3
8   [97.44, 99.04, 88.56]     3     3
9    [0.14, 89.61, 39.95]     1     2
```